# Hibernate : Table doesn't get updated

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having trouble with my hibernate transaction. After execution , table has no values in it and is not updated at all. All my other updates work properly.

Here's the mapping

```
 <class name="LastDownloadedMessage" table="t_imap_lastmsguid">
    <id name="id" column="id" ><generator class="increment"/></id>
    <property name="lastDownloadedMessageUid"><column name="last_msg_uid" /></property>
    <property name="lastUidNext"><column name="next_msg_uid" /></property>
    <property name="folder"><column name="folder_name" /></property>
     <property name="cred"><column name="credential" /></property>
 </class>
```

This is the POJO object :

```
public class LastDownloadedMessage {
    Integer id;
    private String lastDownloadedMessageUid;
    private String lastUidNext;
    private String folder;
    private String cred;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS HERE

    public LastDownloadedMessage() {
        super();
    }
    public LastDownloadedMessage(String lastDownloadedMessageUid,
            String lastUidNext) {
        super();
        this.lastDownloadedMessageUid = lastDownloadedMessageUid;
        this.lastUidNext = lastUidNext;
    }
}
```

and this is the function which is doing the update.

```
    Session ssn=HibernateSessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction txn = ssn.beginTransaction();
    Query query = ssn.createQuery("update LastDownloadedMessage e set e.lastDownloadedMessageUid = :luid , e.lastUidNext = :nextUid where e.folder =:folder and e.cred = :cred");
    query.setParameter("luid",last_downloaded_msg_uid);
    query.setParameter("nextUid", uid_next);
    query.setParameter("folder", folder);
    query.setParameter("cred", credential);
    int result = query.executeUpate();
    txn.commit();
    ssn.flush();
    ssn.close();
```

The function appears to execute properly with no errors . What could be the issue ?

Comment: What's the value of 'result' ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew It's zero .

Comment: What does 'select * from t_imap_lastmsguid where folder_name=folder and credential=credential' return if you execute the sql directly?

Also, I see that the field 'folder' is matched to a column called 'folder_name'. What is folder in the updating-function? Is it a String, a Folder-object. Is the parameter you set as a folder of the right type to match the column folder_name?

Comment: Executing that query returns nothing as the table is empty. Folder is `String` type in both updater as well as POJO object. Only mismatching type here is `credential`. Its `String` in my POJO and the functions but in the table , its `integer`. But won't this issue be handled by hibernate?

Comment: I the `String` types to `int` still the same. Help X-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems to me you are confusing UPDATE with INSERT.
If `result` is zero, it means your WHERE clause didn't match anything, so there's nothing to update.

Also, why are you trying to issue an UPDATE/INSERT on a known (mapped) entity? All you have to do is set your values on your object (LastDownloadedMessage) and then execute a `persist` on your EntityManager. Browse around the web for `EntityManager.persist`.

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed using UPDATE instead of insert. I used persist and everything works now!